# InitializeComponent() got deleted automatically at design time

Tags: c#, .net

I am working with a winform, everything is fine but suddenly i got error

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

and i noticed `InitializeComponent()` method is missing from Designer.cs file and available in Main Partial Class File. I am not able to find the error.

[image: Got Deleted from Designer.cs file and now showing in main partial class file]

[image: Missing InitializeComponent() method from Designer.cs file]

Comment: Code as text, not images!

Comment: Probably your PixelTech component failed for some reason. You can comment the code line that initalizes the component and check if the form gets rendered/painted correctly.

Comment: Clean Solution,